# twitter typeahead remote with backbone

Tags: backbone.js, twitter, typeahead

How do I use typeahead remote with backbone restful services.

```
`$('#member-search').typeahead([
                { 
                name: 'orgs',
                 remote: {
                    url: '/rest/orgLookupService?q=%QUERY'
                 },
                header: '<h3 class="league-name">orgs</h3>'
                }
            ]);`
```

WIth above code I never land in orgLookupService.

Here is my js file with service

```
exports.fetchTypeAhead = function(req, res){
console.log('inside service');
console.log(querystring);
```

};

This is my js file to route rest services

```
app.get('/rest/orgLookupService', organisationResource.fetchTypeAhead);
```

But I can access it from

```
http://localhost:3000/rest/orgLookupService.
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks,
Maria.

Comment: Don't give a array to typeahead function. Just give a object to it. typeahead({}) instead of typeahead([{}]).